# Show that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} (x + x^2 \log \frac{x}{x+1}) = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am self studying real analysis and I found this problem in a book.

We have to show that if $x > 1$ then
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[ x + x^2 \log \frac{x}{x+1} \right] = \frac{1}{2}$$.

I can prove that the sequence is bounded.

**It is bounded below by 0.**
Suppose not, then there exists a $x > 1$ such that
$$x + x^2 \log \frac{x}{x + 1} < 0$$.
Which in turn implies
$$1 + \frac{1}{x} > e^{\frac{1}{x}}$$,
a contradiction.

**It is bounded above by 1.**
Suppose not, then there exists a $x > 1$ such that
$$x + x^2 \log \frac{x}{x + 1} > 1$$.
Which means $1 + \frac{1}{x} < e^{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2}}$.
Which in turn implies
$$\frac{1}{x^2} < \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right)^n}{n!}$$.

Now,
$$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right)^n}{n!} < \sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right)^n = \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right)^2 \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^2} \right)^n = \frac{1}{x^2} \frac{x^2 - 2x + 1}{x^2 - x + 1} < \frac{1}{x^2}$$a contradiction.

However the sequence is not monotonic.
Let $u(x) = x + x^2 \log \frac{x}{x+1}$.
Then $u(183073) \approx 0.5000000077125151$, $u(183074) \approx 0.4999997131235432$ and $u(183089) \approx 0.5000000357104$

Any help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose that you have some problems with accuracy. If $u(x) = x + x^2 \log \frac{x}{x+1}$, then, for 15 significant figures, $u(183073)=0.499998179240151$, $u(183074)=0.499998179250097$, $u(183089)=0.499998179399265$

Comment: May be! However, Python3 confirms my numbers.

`import math

x = 183073

print ( x + ( (x * x) * math.log( x / (x + 1)) ) )`

Comment: I cannot see how you could get numbers larger than $0.5$. The asymptotics is $u(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3 x}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2\right)$ which shows that the value of $0.5$ is approached from below.

Comment: Python3 is giving the numbers. You are correct. The numbers should not be more than $0.5$. But then I think it is a problem of Python approximation. I didn't try to prove that it is monotonic, rather believed the numbers blindly. Also the graph generated by Maxima had shown same problem. Which software you used to generate those numbers?
By the way, can it be shown that this sequence is monotonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $1/x=h$

to get $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{h-\ln(1+h)}{h^2}$$

Now use $\ln(1+h)=h-\dfrac{h^2}2+O(h^3)$

Comment: One can employ L'Hospital as well

Comment: L'Hospital rule is discussed in that book in a chapter much later than the chapter of sequences. The notation $O$ is perfectly fine with me. Thanks a lot.